# SQL Server 2008 get modified details

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have a table attached to a gridview in asp.net.

Lets say a user edits a row and updates the text in a textbox. I need to able to know what column he has modified and highlighted (ie make it bold).

This information needs to persist outside of the asp.net session so it would need to come from the DB.

How to go about pulling this info from the DB?

Comment: When do you update the database and how? You could handle the `TextChanged` events of the textboxes and store the related column name somewhere or you could compare the [`OldValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx) property with the [`NewValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx).

Comment: I am using the OldValues and NewValues but they will only be available per session, I want them to persist even if another user displays the data, hence the DB might come in handy, maybe with a trigger perhaps

Answer (score 1):

Add one more column to of **updateTime** in table and create a afterUpdate trigger which will insert updated time in that column.
Now you can differentiate the rows which have been updated recently from all other rows.